# Could not open input file: C:/Users/snowflex/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/app/artisan

Tags: php, git, heroku, laravel-5, artisan-migrate

I always get this error with my heroku laravel 5 when using the artisan command

```
$ heroku run php /app/artisan
Running php C:/Users/snowflex/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/app/artisan on elvote... starting, run.2723 (Free)
Running php C:/Users/snowflex/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/app/artisan on elvote... connecting, run.2723 (Free)
Running php C:/Users/snowflex/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/app/artisan on elvote... up, run.2723 (Free)
Could not open input file: C:/Users/snowflex/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/app/artisan
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run:

```
composer update
```

If not, check [this here](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3947), this might help: